# Configure X properly to start GUI programs from SSH session

Tags: xorg, x-server, xinit

I've installed `xorg`, `xdm` and `fluxbox` onto a GUI-less minimal Debian virtual machine instance (on GCP), then I've tried to run an application `chromium` or `google-chrome` with GUI. The execution of the program fails with the following message:

```
$ google-chrome
[2631:2631:0905/040834.818761:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[2631:2631:0905/040834.821056:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

If I connect via RDP and open a terminal on GUI then enter the same command, the browser application simply starts as expexted.

If I enter this command from a **putty session**, the program starts in the **RDP session**.

```
$ DISPLAY=:10.0 google-chrome
```

I want to be able to launch programs what use GUI from SSH.
I understand that I need to configure a display related variable, but I don't understand exactly where and how.

- should I hardcode this display variable into `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` script?
- if so, this wouldn't destroy the dynamic display handling behavior of the xorg?
- or is there a more advanced approach how should this work properly?
- isn't there any tutorial (for dummies from scratch) about how this whole xserver should be configured properly?

---

I've copied my `.xinitrc` and `.xsession` files from the internet (because the installation was not smooth), which is probably is not good for the above requirement:

My `.xinitrc` file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi
exec fluxbox
```

My `.xsession` file is:

```
exec startfluxbox
```

Comment: Is `X11Forwarding` enabled in SSH server? Is it enabled in SSH client? Are you trying to run X application as regular user while xdm is running as root?

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to run the application as user, while the xdm is running as root. I'm not sure I understand the reason why I need to enable X11Forwarding in SSH server. I don't want to forward the GUI of the application from the server to my local computer, I just want to run see the GUI of the application on the server (I'm using RDP to connect to it). Could you please explain this part?

Comment: Ah, then you don't need X11Forwarding. But you need authority file for xdm. Usually it is located at `/var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/` with random-generated name but path may differ. Add it to your user's .Xauthority with `sudo cat /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/<auth_file_name> | xauth merge -`. Maybe you'll also need to run `xhost +local:`. For permanent access perhaps you'll need to configure xdm's `DisplayManager.DISPLAY.authFile`. But even if you run application in xdm's X session, there is no window manager yet. Why can't you just login in xdm with RDP?

Comment: And of course `export DISPLAY=:0` before running applications.